# Site workflow to send reminder email to Created By based on status of the item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I want to create site workflow to send a reminder email to created by(emails) when Item created is more than 30 days and choice field called "Status" is "open". When someone has more than one items with status open in list then that person get one reminder mail only

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use **MS Flow** to implement your design.

1.Add the **Recurrence** trigger: You can customize the trigger time and run frequency

2.Add the **Get items** action:

- **Filter Query**: `Created gt 'formatdatetime(addDays(utcNow(),-30,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')' and Status eq 'Open'`

3.Add the **Select** action

4.Add the **Create HTML table** action

- From: **Output** (from Select action)

5.Add the **Send an email (V2)** action

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying to this post. But I want to do this using SharePoint designer